# NON IR Remote Control Replacement for a Samsung UN50KU6300 TV

Tags: television, remote-control, hdtv

I need to replace the remote control of my Samsung UN50KU6300 TV.

My main priority is too find a remote that works like the original did, in that, the remote would work without line of sight with the TV. For example, the remote could be underneath a blanket and it would still control the TV without difficultly.

Base on this, what technology does the original remote use (so I can specify that in my searches for a replacement)?

I'm discovering remotes that claim compatibility, but I'm worried that they won't work the same as the original in terms of the priorities I've discussed.

[image: pic of original remote]

**Update:** I ultimately purchased [remote model BN59-01242A](https://www.newegg.com/p/0X6-04KT-0M0V1?Item=9SIADBSAYC9756). I'll report back with another update after it arrives and I see if it works.

Comment: https://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/2016-uhd-smart-tv-ku6300 is the Support page, for reference, if this issue isn't resolved with what you posted in your Update. If it is the right solution, https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07VSN1KPZ/ref=sspa_dk_detail_1? is a silicone protective case for it.

Comment: @K7AAY - I like that protective case you linked; the bright color will make the dang thing easier to find when digging through my couch! I swear, with kids involved, the best remote for me would be one with a homing device built in.

Comment: TILE stickers https://www.amazon.com/Tile-RE-25002-Sticker-2-Pack/dp/B07W63295C , or a leash.

Comment: @K7AAY Put you comments into an answer, and I'll check it.

Comment: Would not be an 'answer' and therefore would be voided. However, you can upvote comments; there's a faint grey up arrowhead to the left of each comment (except those I have upvoted which turn blue).

Comment: I just check today, and NewEgg voided my order for some unknown reason. I called Samsung and found out that the exact remote model number from my UN50KU6300 tv is [BN59-01260A](http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/ASIN/B07SGPJ2KT/howtoadvicecom). Today, I reordered it via Amazon. I will report back how well it works; it should be perfect. My orange remote cover has already arrived; thanks again for that suggestion.